# How docke run linux container on windows server 2019?

Tags: windows, docker

I downloaded desktop meet some error, and I found the docker desktop didn’t support on windows server.

Then I wanted to run a linux image in windows server, but I can’t find how to trans windows mode to linux mode.And more I didn’t find the dockercli.exe.

So now my question is:
dose windows server support linux mode?
If it does, how to change to such mode?
if not, how to run linux container on windows server 2019?

Answer (score -1):

To run docker on windows server 2019, try this

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-docker-containers-on-windows-server-2019/

You should also install WSL Feature

Comment: should the WSL Feature be a requirement in such method?